# How to fix this "" ESLing error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

This piece of code:

```
 <template v-if="isTag(field, '')">
   {{ getItemValue(item, field)
   ? getItemValue(item, field)
   : '&#8211'; }}
 </template>
```

Is producing this error:

> - invalid expression: missing ) after argument list in
>
>   "\n            "+_s(getItemValue(item, field)
>               ? getItemValue(item, field)
>               : '–';)+"\n          "
>
>   Raw expression: {{ getItemValue(item, field)
>               ? getItemValue(item, field)
>               : '–'; }}

I've stared at that code for ours but I still can't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a semi-colon appearing before a closing brace `;)`. Making the assumption that this is a Vue template, semi-colons do not belong within Vue's template syntax.

```
_s(getItemValue(item, field) ? getItemValue(item, field) : '–';)
                                                              ^^ Here
```

Comment: I think ESLint told me to add that semicolon ... ESLint prank?

Comment: @alex Perhaps ESLint doesn't cooperate well with Vue.

Comment: I think ESLint meant: '&#8211;'